# Lorentz covariant propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation, propagator

So the Feynman propagator for a Klein Gordon is manifestly Lorentz invariant clearly by looking at the momentum space representation written in terms of Lorentz scalars.

But in the case of the Dirac/ fermion propagator one can express the denominator as a Lorentz invariant, yet the numerator appears Lorentz covariant because of the $\gamma \cdot p$ term. Thus is this indicative of a Lorentz covariance ie under Lorentz transformation there is a change in helicity/ polarisation for Dirac spinors?

Comment: The fermion propagator (or $\gamma \cdot p$) is Lorentz invariant, not Lorentz covariant. See more here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/532982/do-lorentz-rotations-transform-the-gamma-matrices-gamma-a

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac propagator $\Delta_{ab}$ is defined to be the solution of the following
differential equation

$$
\left(\gamma. \partial + m \right)^{\phantom{a}c}_{a} \Delta_{cb}(x-y) =
\delta_{b}^{a} \delta^{(4)}(x-y)
$$

subjected to Feynman boundary conditions.
The $a,b$ and $c$ are four-dimensional spinor indices.

This $\Delta_{ab}$ is the two-point
function of the free theory

$$
\langle \bar{\psi}_{a} (x) \psi_{b} (y) \rangle_{\text{free}} = \Delta_{ab} (x - y)
$$

so you are right: due to the two-point function interpretation, you must have Lorentz covariance.

Compare this with a scalar field:

$$
\langle \phi (x) \phi(y) \rangle_{\text{free}} = \Delta(x - y).
$$

You can see manifest Lorentz invariance since $\phi$ is a scalar.

Comment: How do we reconcile the fact that it is a lorentz covariance quantity? does it physically mean that when I measure the propagation of a fermion in two coordinate frames, spin/helicity/something else changes according to two observers?

Comment: For instance, send $p\rightarrow \Lambda p$, then $\Delta_{fermion} \propto \gamma\cdot (\Lambda^{-1} p) + m$, with the denominator unchanged (in Minkowski spacetime/local inertial frame). So inherently the different coordinate system changed the observed helicity?

Comment: How do you reconcile what with what? "does it physically mean that when I measure the propagation of a fermion in two coordinate frames, spin/helicity/something else changes according to two observers?" Yes. If you are worried about this, think a little bit about what the propagator means.

Comment: My intuition tells me because spinors are eigenstates of spin and thus helicity, if I transform the fields, I automatically attain a different projection of helicity along the propagation direction

Comment: Only massless spinors are eigenstates of helicity. For massive spinors helicity does not have to be conserved. Now, for massless spinors, take the massless propagator and boost it, then show that the helicity projection remains the same.

Comment: Surely you mean chirality? I can always find the helicity even for massive fields?

Comment: "Surely you mean chirality?" For massless particles, definite helicity means definite chirality. "I can always find the helicity even for massive fields?" Yes, but it changes under Lorentz boosts.